# Choosing a mysql database based on choice option from a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a web based application of a college system. I want to add an option to select session like (2017-2018, 2018-2019, 2019-2020, 2020-2021 so on). At any time the admin should be able to select a session (like 2017-2018) to load any previous session and a corresponding database from databases should be loaded. By default, current session should be loaded at startup. I am using mysql.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db2018');
```

loads the database of session 2018-2019. Above code is in a php file that is being called using include statement.

index.php has the login information and then main.php is loaded if login is successful

### main.php

```
session_start();

include 'dbh.inc.php';

//rest of the code
```

### dbh.inc.php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db2018');

if (!$conn) {
    die("connection failed". mysql_connect_error());
}
```

I want default database to be the current session (db2018 for now, db2019 for next year session starting in March 2019) that admin decides which one to be and if chooses another session then that session's database should be loaded in dbh.inc.php

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need, but I don't think you need sessions to do that.

Just a simple date check would do.

Comment: So make the database parameter a variable and set that in the form. Or loose the database parameter and use the [`mysqli_db_select()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) function to select the database also based on some user input

Comment: Yes as @Dohab said, you can call $conn depending upon the year, session has no use for your context

Comment: Guys, it was just a bad use of the word SESSION, probably should have used Financial Year

Comment: @RiggsFolly is right. my bad I used the word session and you guys understood it as $_SESSION thing. by session I meant academic session 2018-2019...

Comment: @RiggsFolly how would I pass the value of database parameter through include statement?

Comment: There are a couple of answer that show you how

Comment: yes, problem solved thanx to @Paddy Hallihan . his solution was much helpful. Thank you as well. Thanx to everyone. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML Form:

```
<form>
<select name="year">
<option value="db2018">2017-2018</option>
<option value="db2019">2018-2019</option>
<option value="db2020">2019-2020</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP parse and set SESSION to use in connection:

```
<?php
//start session
session_start();

//if session is not set, set the default to 'db2018'
if(!isset($_SESSION['db_name']) || $_SESSION['db_name']==""){
    $_SESSION['db_name'] = 'db2018';
}

//if the form is posted update the session
if(isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year']!=""){
    $_SESSION['db_name'] = $_POST['year'];
}

//open connection using session variable
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $_SESSION['db_name']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have my year ranges array on the initial page where the admin/user needs to select the year then populated a dropdown list of years when a user select a year would just do an ajax call to the db file.

**Main.php**

```
<?php


    $years = ['2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2020-2021'];

?>

    <select name="year" id="year">
        <option value="0">Please Select Year</option>
        <?php

            foreach($years as $key=>$year){

                echo "<option value=\"$year\">$year</option>";
            }

        ?>
    </select>




    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('document').ready(function(){

            $('#year').on('change',function(){

                    var year = $(this).val();

                    $.ajax({
                      type : "POST",
                      data : {year:year},
                      url   : "dbh.inc.php",
                      dataType : "json",
                      encode   : true,
                      success : function(response){

                            if(response == "success"){

                                alert('database selected success');

                                //redirect to desired page
                            }else{

                                alert(response);
                            }
                      }
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Then

**dbh.inc.php**

```
<?php

    $year = isset($_POST['year']) ? $_POST['year']: null;


    switch($year){


        case '2017-2018':

        $_SESSION['db'] = 'that year db';
        break;

        case '2018-2019':

        $_SESSION['db'] = 'that year database';

        break;

        case '2019-2020':
        $_SESSION['db'] = 'that year database';
        break;

    }

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $_SESSION['db']);

if (!$conn) {
    echo json_encode("connection failed". mysql_connect_error());
}else{

    echo json_encode("success");
}           

?>
```

Comment: thank you so much. however solution shared by @paddy was easier. anyways, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select name="db_session">
<option value="db2018">2017-2018</option>
<option value="db2019">2018-2019</option>
<option value="db2020">2019-2020</option>
</select>
```

when selecting the dropdown, set the selected db name in the session variable and rewrite the code below to use the selected database name which is in the session

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db2018');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 functions first one to connect initially and the second one to reconnect with the different DB name based on what user has selected.

```
<?php
  $dbName = date('Y');
  function connectDB(){
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $dbName);
  }

  function reconnectDB($dbName){
    mysqli_close($conn);
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $dbName);
  }
?>
```

So whenever the user change the school session date you can call the reconnectDB function with the user selected year.